# Fixing CORS and collision errors when Function is deployed

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I am completely new to Azure cloud. When I deployed my Azure Function in to Function app using VS code, in the Azure portal, I am seeing the error says that:

> System.InvalidOperationException : A collision for Host ID 'functionAppName' was detected in the configured storage account.

When I try to run the function using the option Code Test/Run, the Run button is disabled with the error message:

> Running your function in portal requires the app to explicitly accept requests from https://portal.azure.com. This is known as cross-origin resource sharing (CORS).

I have no idea of what these errors all about, since working with Azure is completely new to me. How can I fix these issues?

**Error 1:**

```
AZFD004
Diagnostic event
Error code
AZFD004
Level
Error
Message
A collision for Host ID 'functionAppName' was detected in the configured storage account. For more information, see URL.
Details
System.InvalidOperationException : A collision for Host ID 'functionAppName' was detected in the configured storage account. For more information, see URL.
Hit count
23
Timestamp
October 6, 2023 at 12:30:18 AM GMT+5:30
Help link
```

**Error 2:**

```
Running your function in portal requires the app to explicitly accept requests from https://portal.azure.com. This is known as cross-origin resource sharing (CORS). Click here to add https://portal.azure.com to the allowed origin configuration.
```

`__init__.py`:

```
import azure.functions as func
import sys
import os
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(current_dir))

 # import 'test_run' module
from test_run import func_1, func_2, func_3

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        func_1()  
        func_2()
        func_3()

        name = req.params.get('name')
        if not name:
            return func.HttpResponse("Please pass a 'name' parameter in the query string.", status_code=400)

        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}. The function triggered successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
```

`test_run.py`:

```
def func_1():
    '''some code here'''
def func_2():
    '''some code here'''
def func_3():
    '''some code here
```

Comment: can you please share your function code in order to help you better?

Comment: If you are trying to access any external site in your function, you can add it [here](https://i.imgur.com/Vkpr1L0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your code and test it locally as well as in portal post deployment, it worked as expected for me.

**Code:**

```
import  sys
import  os
import  azure.functions  as  func 
from .test_run  import  func_1,func_2,func_3 

current_dir  =  os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(current_dir))

def  main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

try:
func_1()
func_2()
func_3()  

name  =  req.params.get('name')
if  not  name:
    return  func.HttpResponse("Please pass a 'name' parameter in the query string.", status_code=400)
return  func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}. The function triggered successfully.")

except  Exception  as  e:
return  func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
```

**test_run.py-**

```
def  func_1():
print("Testing func_1")

def  func_2():
print("Testing func_2")

def  func_3():
print("Testing func_3")
```

**Local Test Result-**

While testing, you need pass `name=<anything>` in order to get the result.

[image]

[image]

**In Portal-**

You need to pass the **name** parameter like below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you, this is the script I am using, but still getting the error when triggering the function https://imgur.com/RdKsZk3

Comment: Can you please share the error screenshot? Try to debug the function if you are testing it locally

Comment: Sorry, the error is due to one of the library I use, which is python-tabular. The error occurs in the line while importing this particular library. Thanks for your help. If you do know about this library, help me to fix this please.

Comment: please share the error screenshot, so that I can help you. Are you getting error for azure.functions and test_run?

Comment: created new question since it is different issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77244072/getting-error-while-importing-python-tabular-in-the-script-in-azure-functions

Comment: is your issue related to this thread resolved?

Comment: yes, collision issue is not fixed, I don't have access to make any changes, so I am ignoring the issue for now.

Answer (score 0):

### Error 1

I'm assuming you haven't redacted the above error message and it's verbatim saying `A collision for Host ID 'functionAppName' was detected in the configured storage account. For more information, see URL.`?  I'd be very surprised if your Function App is actually called `functionAppName` since Function App names must be globally unique, so I'd say it looks like you've got a copy + paste error somewhere in your configuration.  Do something like a `git grep -i 'functionAppName'` to search for all instances of the string `functionAppName` in your repo and replace them with the actual name of the Function App.

### Error 2

I'm not quite sure what the question is here?  The error message is telling you that you need to add `https://portal.azure.com/` to the list of allowed origins in the CORS setting for your Function App.  For more info on how to do this this refer to the following MS Docs: [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#cors).

Comment: @Ikhtesam Afrin Error 2 got fixed, thanks for your help. @simon-pearson the actual name is not functionAppName, I have removed the actual name, since posting it in public forum. The error message is ```System.InvalidOperationException : A collision for Host ID 'functionAppName' was detected in the configured storage account.```

Comment: @Ikhtesam Afrin but still I am getting ```500 Internal Server Error``` when I trigger the function using ```post``` method ```"name":"Azure"```. can you please guide me here? I have ```init.py``` which will be triggered, inside that I have called my actual script. Provided the **sample code** above in the question.

Comment: the message when function triggered, I can see is attached the screenshot https://imgur.com/XFD3vDn