# getting error while importing python-tabular in the script in Azure Functions

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, python-import, importerror

I have the script which is used to connect to SSAS model for partition creation, deletion and refresh. Here, for partition creation and deletion, I am using the library called pyadomd.

For refresh, I am using the library called python-tabular. https://pypi.org/project/python-tabular/0.1.7/

I have deployed the code into Azure Function, and when I try to trigger the function, I am getting error in the import statement --> import pytabular. Below is the full exception, please help me to resolve this,

```
Full Exception :
 Exception while executing function
 /Functions.httpTrigger ---> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcException 
 /Result
 /Failure Exception
 /RuntimeError
 /Could not find libmono 

 /  
 '/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py', line 380, in _handle__function_load_request     func = loader.load_function(   
 '/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py', line 44, in call     return func(*args, **kwargs)   
 '/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py', line 132, in load_function     mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)   
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py', line 126, in import_module     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   
 '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>', line 1050, in _gcd_import   
 '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>', line 1027, in _find_and_load   
 '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>', line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked   
 '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>', line 688, in _load_unlocked   
 '<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>', line 883, in exec_module   
 '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>', line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed   
 '/home/site/wwwroot/httpTrigger/__init__.py', line 9, in <module>     from .refresh_automation import main_func   
 '/home/site/wwwroot/httpTrigger/refresh_automation.py', line 6, in <module>     import pytabular   
 '/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pytabular/__init__.py', line 45, in <module>     import clr   
 '/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/clr.py', line 6, in <module>     load()   
 '/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pythonnet/__init__.py', line 36, in load     set_default_runtime()   
 '/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/pythonnet/__init__.py', line 22, in set_default_runtime     set_runtime(clr_loader.get_mono())   
 '/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/clr_loader/__init__.py', line 21, in get_mono     libmono = find_libmono(sgen)   
 '/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/clr_loader/util/find.py', line 67, in find_libmono     raise RuntimeError('Could not find libmono')     
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[] parameters,FunctionInvocationContext context) 
/src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/Workers/WorkerFunctionInvoker.cs 
 /101    
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[] parameters) 
/src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionInvokerBase.cs 
 /82    
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionGenerator.Coerce[T](Task`1 src) 
/src/azure-functions-host/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionGenerator.cs 
 /225    
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments) 
D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs 
 /52    
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeWithTimeoutAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance) 
D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs 
 /581    
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,ILogger logger,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource) 
D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs 
 /527    
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance,FunctionStartedMessage message,FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,ILogger logger,CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs 
 /306    End of inner exception    
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance,FunctionStartedMessage message,FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,ILogger logger,CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs 
 /352    
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    
async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs 
 /108
```

libraries in **requirements.txt**:

```
azure-functions
python-tabular
pyadomd
msal
numpy
pandas
pymsteams
azure-storage-blob
```

import statement inside the `test_run.py`:

```
import pytabular
from pyadomd import Pyadomd
import requests
import json
import msal
import logging
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys
import pymsteams
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, ContainerClient, ContentSettings
import io

def func_1():
   '''rest of the code here'''
   return df
def func_2(df1):
   '''rest of the code here'''
def main_func():
   try:
       df1 = func_1()
       func_2(df1)
   except Exception as e:
       '''some code logic to retry'''
```

code in the `__init__.py`:

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import sys
import os
from .test_run import main_func

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(current_dir))

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    try:
        main_func()
        name = req.params.get('name')
        if not name:
            try:
                req_body = req.get_json()
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                name = req_body.get('name')
        if name:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
                status_code=200
            )
    except Exception as e:
        return  func.HttpResponse(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}", status_code=500)
```

Comment: Can you please share your function code, so that It will be easier to know what all python libraries you are using in your code

Comment: Added the libraries and import statement in the question. not able to copy paste the entire script here due to its length

Comment: are you using `libmono` anywhere in your code?

Comment: no, not using it anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the issue in my environment and got the same error alike you.

Then I noticed below.

[image]

As per the this [link](https://pypi.org/project/python-tabular/0.1.7/), its only supported in windows operating system. So when I tested my function locally it worked but post deployment getting the same error because Linux is the only supported operating system for python runtime stack function app.

[image]

I can see there is a new version of python-tabular is available but it doesn't have any information in it whether it supports Linux or not.

**Local Output:**

[image]